# How to set permissions so Zend Server CE Virtual Host can access a document root under my /Users/me directory on a mac

Tags: virtualhost, zend-server-ce

I am trying to set up Zend Server CE Virtual Host on a Mac running OSX Snow Leopard.

If I put the vhost document root in

/usr/local/zend/apache2/vhosts/site

everything works fine.

If I put it into

/Users/me/Documents/site

I get:

"Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

The permissions for /Users/me/Documents/site are:

drwxrwxrwx   3 me  staff  102 30 Jul 12:33 test

How can I get the zend server daemon to serve files in my Documents directory?